# How to prevent the default browser from opening up when clicking on a link in a TextView?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

I have a text view and contains some links. When I click on the links the default iOS browser opens up. But I want to open my custom web view for this purpose. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

On click of the button you can call a UIViewController with a [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), then you can use the `loadRequest: method` to load your URL.

Comment: There is no button. Its a simple link in the text view, and I tap that.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually done what Oscar recommends.  Problem is, that you really can only assign one "link" to each button.  I would actually like to know more about your problem.  Do you truly have a large amount of text, with multiple HTML links displayed in a multi-line UITextView?  Is the text you're putting into the UITextView static (not-changing) or dynamic (where it changes)?

In either case, I would recommend implementing your text, with links, as local HTML file(s) within your app, and opening them up within the your own UIWebView.  Any link tapped within your own UIWebView will open and stay within your WebView rather than exiting into the standard browser.  This is something I have done on multiple occasions as I have used locally stored HTML for game directions, etc... to be used in-app.  There is a way to make the HTML page have a transparent background to allow your other views behind (like a backing, etc...) to show thtough the text.  I will try to edit this later to give you the line you must add to your HTML files to allow for transparent HTML backing (if that is what you need, as it will make it look / feel more like the default UITextView).

This is also the recommendation Apple gives on their UITextView Class Reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html

Comment: I am fetching tweets from Twitter in my text view. The text contained is combination of normal text and links or may be just links. They are getting generated at the runtime. And then if I click (tap) on any link the default browser opens up.

Comment: If you're fetching the tweets and displaying them in your text view, then can you not search for the links within the tweets and replace them with your custom link before you display them as I said in my answer? If you do this then your app will called when they click on the link and you can display them in your web view? Is the tweet content hidden or read-only?

Comment: Its a read only. I can view the links inside the tweets in the text view. And I can click on them. Now the pain is to open my own Web View not the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its possible to do something like register a  handler for the links overriding the default handler, but if not then is it easy for you to change the links? If so you can launch your app from a link such as:

myappurlscheme://

If there is information in the original link you need to pass it to your app such as

myappurlscheme://http.theoriginalurl.com/somestuff

Then within your app you can extract http.theoriginalurl.com/somestuff and pass it to a UIWebVIew.

This technique is usually used to launch an app, but as your app is already running it will still work and result in a function call to your app delegate.

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: The thing is you can only tap the link in the text view. And when you do that, there is no extraction that you can do. So can't be passed to any Web View. So there is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSURLProtocol` - derive your own class from it and implement the relevant methods (check out the documentation it should be self explanatory, if not come back here with any questions).

You'll register your class in your app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

When a link is clicked in the text view you'll get the chance to intercept the url and prevent the browser from launching. You can do what you want with the url once you have intercepted it - such as loading it within a `UIWebView` for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a UITextViewDelegate Method - textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange: which returns a Bool Variable.

So just create your custom UIWebView in this method and load URL in this webview and return No for preventing the default browser from opening that link.

`- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange{
    NSLog(@"%@",URL);
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
    SDWebViewController *webViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebViewController"];
    webViewController.strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[URL absoluteString]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
    return NO;
}`

Then load the URL in WebView in SDWebViewController class object.